# how to dynamically add view to a custom cursor adapter..?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

how can i dynamically add a view to a custom cursor adapter.. where each row of list view look like..

```
<?XML version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">



<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight=".9"
android:id="@+id/book_name" android:text="Default"
android:textStyle="bold" />




<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tick"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="NOT ADDED" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and the adapter looks like..::

```
package com.himanshu;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListViewAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter 
{ 
    static String[] FROM={DbHelper.BOOK_NAME };
    static int[] TO ={R.id.book_name};

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, Cursor c)
{ 
super(context, R.layout.row, c, FROM, TO);
}
// This is where the actual binding of a cursor to view happens
@Override
public void bindView(View row, Context context, Cursor cursor) 
{ 
super.bindView(row, context, cursor);

int flag = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.FLAG));
if(flag==1)
{
TextView tick = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tick); 
tick.setText("ADDED"); 
}
}
}
```

i have used SimpleCursorAdapter because i want to access data via database...
now while the activity is running there are some insertions in the database which i have to show on the list view..

Comment: insertions means and what you want and what was going ?

Comment: actually some more entries are been added or u can say some new rows are inserted... so i need to show these newly added rows also...

Comment: how you add new Row i mean Any Button click and add new Row Be Clear...

Comment: after a button click a new row is added ...

Answer (score 1):

You should use a CustomAdapter and override the getView(position) to implement this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

When a data change you have to change the cursor using

```
changeCursor(your_new_cursor);
```

The cursor you gave before to the adapter will be closed.

Comment: now if i change cursor then the computation for the new cursor has to be performed form the begining i.e it will again create the list view from scratch.... but i just want to add newly inserted rows.. let say earlier i had 10 rows in the database so 10 items in the list view and now i add 1 more row so correspondingly 11 items in the list view but i just want the computation for this extra added row nor for the earlier 10 rows also....